# DD-WRT Force New WAN IP Address

Tags: router, ip, dd-wrt, wan

Is there a way to force a new WAN IP Address with DD-WRT? I know there was a way before that would require temporarily setting a new Local IP or Modifying the WAN but I do not remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was under **[MAC Address Clone](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/MAC_Address_Clone)**

> To enable MAC Cloning, simply click the option under the tab itself. You will have the option of either "Get current PC MAC" or you can input one yourself. Get current PC MAC is primarily used when establishing a service with an ISP that requires it, such as Comcast. The other option of manually entering a MAC address can be used for many things such as linking two routers together, or "spoofing" to force your ISP to give you a new IP address.